# alembic and getting the last inserted value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using alembic to manage my database structure.

After adding a table using id as Integer and primary key the id column will be an autoincrement-column. How do I query the data in the upgrade script so I'm sure that I get the correct id (I know it's 1 in this specific case)?

I know how to

```
#creating the table
op.create_table(
    'srv_feed_return_type',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String(50), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created', sa.DateTime, server_default=func.now(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created_by', sa.String(50), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('last_updated', sa.DateTime, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('last_updated_by', sa.String(50), nullable=False)
)

#table for operations
srv_feed_return_type = table('srv_feed_return_type',
                             column('name'),
                             column('created'),
                             column('created_by'),
                             column('last_updated'),
                             column('last_updated_by'))

#bulk insert
op.bulk_insert(srv_feed_return_type,
               [
                   {'name': 'dataset',
                    'created': datetime.now(), 'created_by': 'Asken',
                    'last_updated': datetime.now(), 'last_updated_by': 'Asken'}
               ])
```

I know I can do update but how do I do a select using something similar like below?

```
op.execute(
    srv_feed_return_type.update().\
        where(srv_feed_return_type.c.name==op.inline_literal('dataset')).\
        values({'name':op.inline_literal('somethingelse')})
        )
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that there won't be any other processes modifying your newly created table until your migration is finished?

Comment: for this example yes but I know that it'll be one here. in another migration it will not be 1 anymore. i need to know the id of a specific return type.

Comment: What database are you using for your app and is there possibility to more to another db - is there requirement to have application be database agnostic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First to have auto-increment column you'll need to modify table schema definition to have Sequence passed for primary key column: `sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, Sequence('srv_feed_r_t_seq'),primary_key=True),`

```
#creating the table
op.create_table(
    'srv_feed_return_type',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, Sequence('srv_feed_r_t_seq'),primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String(50), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created', sa.DateTime, server_default=func.now(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created_by', sa.String(50), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('last_updated', sa.DateTime, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('last_updated_by', sa.String(50), nullable=False)
)
```

Now about how to get PK id:

`op.execute` and `op.bulk_insert` doesn't return you any results. But you can get same connection used for these operations.

After doing `bulk_insert` or `execute(table.update ...)` you can run select query in the same context and retrieve PK id for the record of interest:

```
connection = op.get_bind()
r = connection.execute(srv_feed_return_type.select().where(...))
for row in r:
    pk_id = r['id']
    """or something more sophisticated"""
```

You'll need to specify proper filter in where clause to make sure that you identified record you recently changed in unique way.

Here is [some example of similar functionality](https://code.google.com/p/bungeni-portal/source/browse/bungeni.buildout/trunk/data/alembic/versions/2df675e61324_added_group_role_fie.py?spec=svn10645&r=10645), but it has hardcoded select queries

Comment: Will try. Thanks! Btw, by defining Integer and primary_key=True it will automatically be an auto-increment.

Comment: Thank you for hint about automatic autoincrement. It didn't work for me when I was using Oracle - so I had to use sequence explicitly

Comment: Maybe it's different for Oracle... maybe I should add it to my code for good measure to be safe.